# Como faço para sempre ir atualizando a planilha em Excel sem substituir os dados anteriores?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

Eu construí um simples código em Python usando o Pandas (junto com o ExcelWriter), esse foi o código:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Empresa': [client1, client2, client3, client4, client5, client6, client7, client8, client9, client10],
                'Colaborador': [collaborator1, collaborator2, collaborator3, collaborator4, collaborator5, collaborator6, collaborator7, collaborator8, collaborator9, collaborator10],
                'Status': 'Planejado N/ Executado',
                'CCU': [ccu1, ccu2, ccu3, ccu4, ccu5, ccu6, ccu7, ccu8, ccu9, ccu10],
                'Data': [today, today, today, today, today, today, today, today, today, today]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('DadosOperacionaisPy.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        
writer.save()
```

O meu problema é que eu gostaria de "montar um banco de dados" todas as vezes que eu executasse esse comando novamente, ou seja, sempre pegasse as informações do código e fosse adicionando a planilha sem substituir nenhuma das informações adicionadas anteriormente, mas toda a vez que executo o código ele apaga os dados anteriores e substitui pelos novos dados.

> Caso isso seja simples de resolver, desculpe, sou bem iniciante ainda
> :)

Comment: Tive um problema parecido e a única maneira que encontrei para resolver foi lendo as informações e salvando em uma variável e depois escrevendo de novo. Tenta assim **pd.read_excel(arquivo, sheet_name=''Sheet1')**

Comment: Use o modo anexar `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('DadosOperacionaisPy.xlsx', mode="a", engine='xlsxwriter')`

Comment: Nenhuma dessas opções funcionaram da maneira que eu gostaria, mas obrigado pela ajuda :), sigo procurando uma maneira de encontrar como fazer isso funcionar.

Answer (score -1):

Se as opções que o pessoal comentou não funcionam pra você, talvez um modo um pouco mais rústico possa resolver. Tente isso aqui:

1: usando o seu dataset, temos a saída abaixo:

```
pd.read_excel('DadosOperacionaisPy.xlsx')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2: criamos a função abaixo, que será invocada cada vez que você quiser adicionar novas linhas, no formato de dataframe, ao arquivo excel já salvo:

```
def xls_writer(df):
    df_strd = pd.read_excel('DadosOperacionaisPy.xlsx')
    df      = df_strd.append(df)
    writer  = pd.ExcelWriter('DadosOperacionaisPy.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Exemplo:

Criando dataframe de teste:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Empresa': ['client1', 'client2', 'client3', 'client4', 'client5', 'client6', 'client7', 'client8', 'client9', 'client10'],
            'Colaborador': ['collaborator1', 'collaborator2', 'collaborator3', 'collaborator4', 'collaborator5', 'collaborator6', 'collaborator7', 'collaborator8', 'collaborator9', 'collaborator10'],
            'Status': 'Planejado N/ Executado',''
            'CCU': ['ccu1', 'ccu2', 'ccu3', 'ccu4', 'ccu5', 'ccu6', 'ccu7', 'ccu8', 'ccu9', 'ccu10'],
            'Data': 'tomorrow'})
```

Usando a função xls_writer, que irá ler o arquivo excel local e adicionar o dataframe novo como novas linhas abaixo daquelas já existentes, usando o método append, do Pandas.

```
xls_writer(df_2)
```

Lendo o arquivo excel para confirmar a operação:

```
pd.read_excel('DadosOperacionaisPy.xlsx')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]